# Div's css style now showing up when javascript is inside of it

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pretty simple page (for practicing right now). I have a div with a red border and a blue background. Inside the div is a  tag calling an external js file. The js is working, but then the border of the div disappears.

Here is the code.

```js
var myArray = [
  "Item one",
  "Item two",
  "Item three"
];

var randomItemOne = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = randomItemOne;
```

```css
.box1 {
  border: solid 2px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random Text Selector</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rt_style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="box1">
    <script src="js/random.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in js file, have provide any styling for box class??

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML` will replace the contents of `body` tag with `randomItemOne`. What else can you expect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [
  "Item one",
  "Item two",
  "Item three"
];

var randomItemOne = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementsByClassName("box1")[0].innerText = randomItemOne;
```

```css
.box1 {
  border: solid 2px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random Text Selector</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rt_style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="box1">
    <script src="js/random.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I think this is what you are trying to achieve. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I'm just starting to get the hang of JS. Now it's a matter of making it play nicely with my actual web page.

Comment: If I could put in one more question, how can I get this script to populate, say, three different divs (div1, div2, div3) with completely random results for each? Thanks.

Comment: You would just duplicate the <div class="box1"> with your new boxes and in the document.getElementsByClassName you do [i] for every single box

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks again. This is working so simply.

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to put the script inside the `<div>` -- it's generally recommended that all your `<script>` tags go after `</body>` or inside of `<head>` (opinions vary on which of these is preferred).

Comment: I know I just copy pasted your html